# How to typeset numbers and short consecutive math statements in running text

Tags: punctuation, inline

Which version should one use?

`The numbers $1,2,3$ are natural numbers.`

`The numbers $1,\,2,\,3$ are natural numbers.`

`The numbers $1$, $2$, $3$ are natural numbers.`

Considering using the last version, what about the following sentence then?

`The numbers $1,2,3 \in \mathbb Z$ are natural numbers.` The spacing is different. What should I do in order to make the notation in the document consistent?

More general with statements:

`For $statement 1, statement 2, statement 3$ we have`

`For $statement 1,\, statement 2,\, statement 3$ we have`

`For $statement 1$, $statement 2$, $statement 3$ we have`

For example:

`For $u,v \in \mathbb Z, u>v, \gcd(u,v)=1$ we have`

`For $u,v \in \mathbb Z$, $u>v$, $\gcd(u,v)=1$ we have`

Comment: for the first type, is it permissible for the line to break between the numbers?  if so, the third version is best.  for the second type, those aren't really math, so omit the `$` signs; i'd also be inclined to "tie" each element: `statement~1`, etc., so they *don't* break at the end of a line.

Comment: Yes, line breaks of course. I don't mean the statements literally. I'll update my question.

Comment: i find that treating each statement separately (returning to "text" for the comma and space) is preferable.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spacing is most consistent when each statement is handled separately, switching back to text between them.  That way more complicated lists aren't treated as one large math element.  In text, those run the risk of margin breaks.

In addition, with many font packages (mathpazo, for instance) math commas are distinct from text commas, and so there is a visible difference between the two ways of typesetting the lists.  Of course, this detail speaks more to personal taste.  See this question for an example.

[How to deal with different commas in text and math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195528/how-to-deal-with-different-commas-in-text-and-math-mode)

With respect to your specific examples, for in-line text, there is no need to put the digits in math mode; the following suffices.

"The numbers 1, 2, 3 are natural numbers."

To keep spacing as close to identical for the expression $1,2,3 \in \mathbb Z$, you may replace with "1, 2, $3 \in \mathbb Z$".  This is *not* highly advised, as the expression may be broken for lines, and this may be less clear when using variables.

My best advice for more general cases is to treat each statement separately, in its own set of $$. In your last pair, the second option

"For $u,v \in \mathbb Z$, $u>v$, $\gcd(u,v)=1$ we have"

is preferable in almost all cases.

Comment: What I noticed is the different space. With the method $..., ..., ...$ there is a different space than with $....$, $....$, $....$.

Comment: Correct.  Math mode disregards simple spaces, which is why they must be forced with commands like \,

Comment: How should one type enumerations of numbers in display math then? \\[1,2,3,4\\] or \\[1,\,2,\,3,\,4\\]? I'm confused.

Comment: Now this is more of an individual preference issue.  Quick question: are you intending to enumerate simply those numbers, or do they perhaps refer to a list outside the display math environment?

Comment: "are you intending to enumerate simply those numbers"
Yes, this.

Comment: Got it.  Then it comes down to your taste.  If you want to see the spaces between each, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, you will need to force them via something like the \, command.  Granted, this diverges a bit from your original question (concerning in-line text).

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: re whether numbers should be math or not, see the tugboat article by knuth, ["Typesetting *Concrete Mathematics*"](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf).  this is the basis of the rationale for my comment on the original question, where i said that the numbers in the first example are math, and in the second, are not.

Comment: Would you accept a different spacing between `The numbers $1$, $2$, $3$ are natural numbers.` and `The numbers $1,2,3 \in \mathbb Z$ are natural numbers.`?

Comment: Just  one more question: In text mode, should one write `$a,b \in A$` or `$a$, $b \in A$` or `$a,\,b \in A$`?